# How to properly use oneOf and anyOf in Rest Schema?

Tags: post-meta, rest-api

I have asked this before at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087780/how-to-properly-use-oneof-and-anyof-in-wp-rest-schema), now I'm  here to be more wp specific and bring more context - as I did some advance on this.

Seeing [this use of oneOf](https://github.com/ajlende/gutenberg/blob/c9012970d5df764d06cfb1bab4958e00282a118c/lib/class-wp-rest-image-editor-controller.php#L52) has made me change my schema to this structure below:

```php
array(
    'type'         => 'object',
    'show_in_rest' => array(
        'schema' => array(
            'type'       => 'object',
            'properties' => array(
                'tipo' => array(
                    'type'  => 'string',
                    'name'  => 'tipo',
                    'enum'  => array(
                        '...',
                    ),
                ),
                'data' => array(
                    'type'   => 'array',
                    'items'  => array(
                        'type'  => 'object',
                        'oneOf' => array(
                            array(
                                'properties'           => array(
                                    'dia'         => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'dia',
                                    ),
                                    'hora_inicio' => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'hora_inicio',
                                    ),
                                    'hora_fim'    => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'hora_fim',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'name'                 => 'data_unica',
                                'title'                => 'Data única',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'properties'           => array(
                                    'periodicidade' => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'periodicidade',
                                        'enum'        => array(
                                            '...'
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    'dia_inicial'   => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'dia_inicial',
                                    ),
                                    'dia_final'     => array(
                                        'type'        => 'string',
                                        'name'        => 'dia_final',
                                    ),
                                    'hora_inicial'  => array(
                                        'type'   => 'string',
                                        'name'   => 'hora_inicial',
                                    ),
                                    'hora_final'    => array(
                                        'type'   => 'string',
                                        'name'   => 'hora_final',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'name'                 => 'data_corrente',
                                'title'                => 'Data corrente',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

The request is:

```json
meta: {
    "datas": {
        "tipo": "UNICA",
        "data": [{
            "dia": "2022-10-21",
            "hora_inicio": "",
            "hora_fim": ""
        }]
    }
}
```

And the response:

```json
{
    "code": "rest_additional_properties_forbidden",
    "message": "dia is not a valid property of Object.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're specifying this schema in a `register_meta()` call for a metakey named `datas` - is that correct? Or is this being used somewhere else? Which endpoint are you sending this request to?

Comment: exacly @bosco, i'm using `register_meta` and using a block that renders a form and mount that request

Comment: Hmmm strange - that looks like a valid use of `oneOf` to me. The only weird bit I see across the whole schema is using `name` attributes throughout, which do not serve a purpose in JSON Schema, nor do they in WordPress to the best of my knowledge. One thing you might try is removing `"type": "object"` from the `"items"` definition and adding it to each of the possible sub-schemas. I don't have a strong basis for this - I think either is technically valid. Failing that, I will try to replicate this myself in the next few days if no one else sorts it out!

Comment: I'm passing the `name` attribute to use the same schema to dinamically generate components for the block, but I probably could use the key instead the value for this. My first attempt was without the type for `items`, but this throws an error in `debug.log` sayind that meta was registered incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing in WordPress v6.0.1, it seemed that:

1. We need to set the (default/initial) `type` of the `data.items` to `null` instead of `object`. (and yes, the type must be set, or else the API response would be invalidated with many "undefined index" notices)
2. For each item, i.e. an array in the `oneOf` or `anyOf`, set the `type` to `object`.

So your `data` schema should look like this, but I purposely used `anyOf` (see explanation below):

```php
'data' => array(
    'type'  => 'array',
    'items' => array(
        'type'  => null,
        'anyOf' => array(
            array(
                'type'       => 'object',
                'properties' => array( ... ),
                'title'      => 'Data única',
            ),
            array(
                'type'       => 'object',
                'properties' => array( ... ),
                'title'      => 'Data corrente',
            ),
        ), // end anyOf
    ), // end items
), // end data
```

And the reason why I did **not** use `oneOf`, is because it caused an error with the code `rest_one_of_multiple_matches` and the message `meta.datas[data][0] matches Data única and Data corrente, but should match only one`.

- You could avoid that issue by using unique schemas, e.g. add `enum` to the `dia`'s schema or change the `hora_inicio`'s `type` to `number`, but that is up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks Sally, I'll try this as soon as I can!

Comment: That's it! Thank you Sally. So for the oneOf its not about the propertie's keys, but propertie's schema? Because my schema have different properties inside each of oneOf....

Comment: Yes, but more precisely - the *value* will be checked against both schemas, and thus for example the string `2022-10-21` resulted in the `rest_one_of_multiple_matches` error, because that string/value passed the validation for (at least) one of the properties in *both* your schemas.

Comment: @SallyCJ having to explicitly set `'type' => null` seems really nutty to me at a glance - like maybe worthy of a Trac ticket, or issue to include it in the docs somewhere. Did you glean any other insight into that wonkiness?

Comment: Hey @bosco, sorry for the late reply! I agreed that it could be a bug in core, and that the `'type' => null` was actually just a workaround  As for the other insight, maybe now in v6.0.2 there is, but back then I (tried; however I) couldn't find a better workaround.. So did you end up opening a Trac ticket for this?